# Yii2- get from related table name to add to Sluggable

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Yii2. How can i get data from the related table and add it to Sluggable behavior.
In the example below, I want for every book add slug-title like "Book House, author Greenberg".

```
class Books extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => "Book" . $this->name . ", author " . $this->getAuthor->name,
            //'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::className(), ['id' => 'author_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by related table.What is your exact need and what problem are you facing.Do you need an attribute called title which has the value of book name and author name combined.Why are you using the behavior here.Add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a callback for the sluggable behavior like so:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class'=>SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'value'=>function ($event) {
                $parts = ['Book', $this->name, 'author', $this->author->name];
                return Inflector::slug(implode('-', $parts));
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

My example will output a slug like this: `book-house-author-greenberg` which is more best practice for slugs than your version. Anyway...if you still prefer the way you described above, simply change the return value.

The doc for the feature used in my example is [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/behaviors/SluggableBehavior.php#L82).